# Pass a javascript map to json wcf service

Tags: javascript, json, wcf, dictionary

I would like to pass an associative array to a json wcf service.

So in JavaScript I have something akin to this:

```
var map = { };
map['a'] = 1;
map['b'] = 2;
map['c'] = 3;
```

And in my wcf service I want to expect a Dictionary:

```
[OperationContract][WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void setDictionary(Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary);
```

But it sends the map as an [Object object] rather than serializing it because the 'map' is actually just an object I'm assigning properties to.

Does anyone know how I can serialize it to correctly to get it deserialized as a Dictionary object by the WCF service?

Comment: Have you tried [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function? `echo JSON.stringify(map);` should output a string: `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}`

Comment: It does but the wcf throws: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, WCF does not represent `Dictionary` as JSON objects - it represents them as arrays of key/value pairs instead. So to send that map to the WCF service, you'll need to covert it appropriately (see code below).

Another alternative is to use a custom message formatter, which knows how to populate dictionaries based on JSON objects. For more information on message formatters, check this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx).

This shows one way of passing that object to your service:

Service.svc:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="StackOverflow_15001755.Service"
                CodeBehind="StackOverflow_15001755.svc.cs" 
                Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Service.svc.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace StackOverflow_15001755
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class Service
    {
        static Dictionary<string, int> dictionary;

        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public void setDictionary(Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary)
        {
            dictionary = myDictionary;
        }

        [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Dictionary<string, int> getDictionary()
        {
            return dictionary;
        }
    }
}
```

Test.html (HTML/JS code, using jQuery for the ajax call):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/json2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function StackOverflow_15001755_Test() {
            function dictionaryToKVPArray(obj) {
                var data = [];
                for (var key in obj) {
                    data.push({ Key: key, Value: obj[key] });
                }

                return data;
            }

            function KVPArrayToDictionary(arr) {
                var result = {};
                arr.forEach(function (item) {
                    result[item.Key] = item.Value;
                });

                return result;
            }

            var map = {};
            map['a'] = 1;
            map['b'] = 2;
            map['c'] = 3;
            var data = dictionaryToKVPArray(map);

            var baseUrl = "/StackOverflow_15001755.svc";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: baseUrl + '/setDictionary',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ myDictionary: data }),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#result').text('Sent the dictionary');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: baseUrl + '/getDictionary',
                        success: function (result) {
                            var newMap = KVPArrayToDictionary(result);
                            $('#result2').text(JSON.stringify(newMap));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="StackOverflow 15001755" onclick="StackOverflow_15001755_Test();" /><br />
    <div id='result'></div><br />
    <div id='result2'></div><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your dictionaryToKVPArray() method is just what I needed for this! Thanks =) Marked as the answer because it shows exactly how to pass the correct data to the WCF service to deserialize a Dictionary object, as well as getting it back into javascript again!

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get this working by using `JSON.stringify(map)` to get a serialized version of the map. Then passing it to WCF service as a string rather than a Dictionary and deserializing it myself in the method using the [Json.Net framework](http://json.codeplex.com/).

**Serialized Map:**

```
{'a':'0','b':'1','c':'2'}
```

**WCF Service:**

```
[OperationContract][WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void doDictionaryStuff(string serializedMap);
```

**Deserializing it in the WCF service using the [Json.Net framework](http://json.codeplex.com/):**

```
public void doDictionaryStuff(string serializedMap)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> map = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,int>>(serializedMap);
    //do stuff with the dictionary.
}
```

It's not ideal, but does work.